# Using Node Reference without popup?

Tags: drupal

I am using two content types company and Employee . I am using node reference here(Company -> Employee). Within the Company form , the Employee node comes as a popup ,Employee form need to bring the display and functionality to the company form and should keep the node reference. .

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, embedding one form in another is nearly impossible in Drupal. That is due to its form-handling and node-handling system.

If you want such relationships, you often need to write a simple, small module that maintains relationships in the database, offers forms to insert/update them and ways to extend nodes with your relational behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Best I could suggest is an iFrame holding the employee form - but still it's not very elegant.